# How to read a .shd file in C++?

Tags: c++

I am creating a project in c++ for getting JobSettings of a job in a queue from .shd file.Can anyone please suggest me which API is used for reading .shd file?

Comment: The file format is officially undocumented, but you can find what has been reverse engineered [here](http://www.undocprint.org/formats/winspool/shd).

Comment: Thank you so much the link is quite beneficial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about the shadow file from the Windows spooler, take a look at this site and code accordingly - http://www.undocprint.org/formats/winspool/shd

Please note that this format is undocumented and so could change ever so often.

Comment: Thank you I am going to check the same and will revert in case of any other doubt.